# Why is my javascript parameter giving me a "It may be inaccessible due to a protection level." error?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, parameters, inline-code

My code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function jsFullPath(relPath) {
            var hidefield = document.getElementById('HiddenField1');
            hidefield.value = relPath;
            var fullPathStr = '<%= fullPath(hidefield.value) %>';
        }
</script>

Public Function fullpath(ByVal relPath As String) As String

    Dim fullPathStr As String = Server.MapPath(relPath)
    Return fullPathStr
End Function
```

Everytime I compile I get that error. I don't understand why. It should work.

Comment: Do you get the error if you rename either the JS parameter name or the VB parameter name?

Comment: Yes, I do. Am I referencing a keyword by mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you are trying to pass a JavaScript variable to your VB method. This unfortunately will not work, as the page has already been parsed and output to the browser (already left the server) by the time your JavaScript is being executed.

One option would be to retrieve this value through the use of ajax.

If you already have the value of the hidden field, can you do something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function jsFullPath() {
            return '<%= Server.MapPath('HiddenField1.Value') %>';
        }
</script>
```

Comment: That code did work. But not the way I wanted it to. I guess I have to use AJAX. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing **hidefield** (a JavaScript object) inside of a server tag. The exception is essentially telling you that hidefield is not defined on the server.

For this to work, the fullpath method needs to be invoked via Ajax.

Comment: I am? The script tag is a server tag? Honestly I didn't know. In any case, I have a ASP.NET HiddenField control on the page and am passing the js parameter to the HiddenField (hidefield).

Comment: @dotnetN00b, anything inside <%= %> tags is parsed at the server.